# Number of Iterations to maximize flow given recurrence relation

Tags: graph-theory, network, network-flow

I have proven that there is always an augmenting path of capacity at least $\frac{F}{|E|}$. How do I use this to bound the number of rounds given that I use a relation to increase the flow by a fraction of the flow left to go (i.e.):

If the flow after i iterations has size $F_{k}$ then $F_{k+1} \geq F_i + \frac{F-F_k}{|E|}$. I'm attempting to provide an upper bound to the number of iterations and trying to find a clear/explicit bound in terms of $F$. I've reached teh relation: $$
(F_{k+1}-F_k)(|E|) \geq F-F_k
$$

Any ideas?

Comment: What's $F$? (And what's $k$? Do you mean to use $k$ as an index instead of $i$? But you have both $F_i$ and $F_k$ in the same formula...)